# Unable to open a PDF document in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, pdf

I have a PDF file in SharePoint 2010, I am not able to open it

When I open the URL, it loads up to like 70% and then it stops there

When I try to download, it fails the first time and then when I click retry, it works every time

The file doesn't seem to be corrupt, but it is not opening up.

Any ideas on troubleshooting this?

Comment: If you open the console in your browser (F12) - do any errors appear when the download fails?

Comment: @RuneSperre No, no errors appear in the console. When I click download a copy, it fails the first time and when I click retry it works

Comment: Have you tried different browsers? Do other users experience the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

How large is that PDF document? reupload the PDF  document and compare the results.

Can you open other PDF documents?

Try to upload another small PDF file and compare whether you can open the pdf document.

Set Browser File Handling to Permissive for a web application in the General settings page in SharePoint 2010 Central Administration.

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989013/cant-open-pdf-files-in-sharepoint-2010-with-internet-explorer